# How to stop macOS from making bell sound on moving line down in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I'm using macOS Mojave (10.14.2) and VSCode (1.31.1).

My issue is that every time I use the "Move Line Down" command using <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Down arrow</kbd>, I get the bell sound that signifies some kind of error. However, when I use the "Move Line Up" command using <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Up arrow</kbd>, there is no error sound.

It's been like this for as long as I can remember. I even checked the shortcuts to make sure nothing else is mapping to this shortcut, but I couldn't find any other commands mapping to the same shortcut. The strange thing is that when I click on the command from the menu, there is no error. I feel that this points to something but I can't seem to figure out what's causing this.

**EDIT**: Just realized that this is an open issue and the command is making noise [due to it being blocked in Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2617).

Answer (score 24):

This appears to be an issue with Chromium (used by Electron, used by VSCode). There's a workaround here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2617#issuecomment-571447707
I'll copy the gist of it here for convenience:

> You can establish system-global key bindings for the key combinations
> ^⌘←, ^⌘↓, and ^⌘→ that are mapped to no operation ("noop"). Simply
> having these declared as valid keystrokes at the OS level eliminates
> the system beep that occurs even when a Chromium app accepts and
> handles the keystroke.
>
> In order to establish this, you need to create a
> ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict – note that you'll
> probably need to create the directory as well, and that the directory
> name is plural (Bindings), but the file name is singular (Binding).
> This should be in your user Library folder, not the /Library folder or
> the /System/Library folder.
>
> The file should be a text file with these contents:
>
> ```
> {
>   "^@\UF701" = "noop";
>   "^@\UF702" = "noop";
>   "^@\UF703" = "noop";
> }
> ```
>
> ^ means Ctrl, @ means Command, and \UF701, \UF702, and \UF703 are
> the codes for the three arrow keys. There's a nice reference Gist for
> this file's syntax here:
> https://gist.github.com/trusktr/1e5e516df4e8032cbc3d I have attached a
> copy of my file in case that's easier for folks.

Also: don't forget to restart VSCode after adding that file! You have to restart for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Hey, I was receiving the sound when pressing Ctrl + Option + Command + DownArrow as well. `"^@~\UF701" = "noop";` didn't work for me. Any suggestions? I'm getting crazy trying combinations and not getting this sound to stop

Comment: Opening up about your problems really helps. After 30 seconds I found the solution: `"@^~\UF701" = "noop";`

Comment: For Sonoma 14.4 solution check here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2617#issuecomment-1988768016

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solutions already provided I needed to do some changes to make it work on Sonoma 14.4+

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2617#issuecomment-1988768016

```
{
    "@^\UF701" = "noop:";
    "@^\UF702" = "noop:";
    "@^\UF703" = "noop:";
    "@~^\UF701" = "noop:";
}
```

Basically I needed to add the `:` at the end of `noop` and invert the order for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + DownArrow

Comment: This worked for me on Sonoma 14.4, weird!